# Load text file to hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

If there is extra column added at the end to the pipe delimited  file which is converted into a hive table, do I have to modify my hive script if I don't need this extra column

Answer (score 0):

It will not take last columns, It will read only the columns as per the create table statement. I think if you dont need the new column, you wont have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Demo

**bash**

```
mkdir /tmp/mydata
cat>/tmp/mydata/myfile.txt
A|B|C
D|E|F
G|H|I
```

**hive**

```
create external table mytable (c1 string,c2 string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
stored as textfile
location 'file:///tmp/mytable/'
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+----+----+
| c1 | c2 |
+----+----+
| A  | B  |
| D  | E  |
| G  | H  |
+----+----+
```